# Questionable review audit of a dupe

Tags: support, review-queues, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, review-suspension

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/19063667) in the Triage section of the Reviews. The time stamp on the question was `asked Feb 18 at 17:26`, so I thought, *surely, this question must have been asked before*.

With the help of a Google search, I came up with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18162522/what-does-return-this-mean-in-c) which was `asked Aug 10 '13 at 13:49` (obviously before the question in review section). It has 6 answers, which answer the review question.

So, I flagged the review question with a duplicate of the old question. To my surprise, it was a (false positive) review audit which I failed, resulting in a suspension. I'm pretty sure it's a duplicate. (Even, the titles are almost the same)

Please help me understand how that question is not a duplicate.

Edit: If it is a bad review question, can anything be done about the suspension?

Comment: FWIW, I close voted the question as duplicate for you.

Comment: I'm removed the review ban. This may not have been a great audit but you've failed others which were definitely clear. Moving forward, please take your time and review carefully - if in doubt - don't be afraid to skip.

Comment: The question has now been closed.

Comment: @JonClements This is definitely a bug in the audit system though. The audit system cannot possibly tell if flagging for dupe is a correct review or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't worry, you're a good reviewer who was just presented with a bad audit. You took the correct action in this specific review audit.

I've gone through both questions and I agree with you, so I've close-voted the audited question as a duplicate. It should no longer be used as an audit.

The audit selection system is flawed. People may have cast upvotes because the question was written in a good manner, which made the audit system think it's a good post, and wrongly picked it as a positive audit. See this post on MSE: [upvoting duplicate questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/174755/350567)